# Why the printf() that precede the fork() gets executed even after the fork()?

Tags: c, unix, fork, system-calls

If after a `fork()` is called the program should continue from the first instruction following the fork, why then the word START gets printed two times?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
        int pid;
        printf("START...");
        pid = fork();
        printf("%d: I've got %d\n", getpid(), pid);
        return 0;
}
```

For example a possible output is:

> START...605: I've got 606
>
> START...606: I've got 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you didn't flush the output buffer and so the text exists in both parent and child's output buffer after the `fork()`.

Add `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf()` and see the difference.

Comment: You can also add newline ('\n') to the end of the string and the buffer should be flushed.

Comment: @ciamej Yes, however that will give (slightly) different output.

Comment: @SergeyA I didn't know it was a dupe.  Also why haven't you asked the same question of dasblinkenlight?

Comment: @SergeyA If you believe it's a dupe then simply mark the question, rather than engaging me in conversation.

Comment: I did. And full disclosure - not the downvoter either. I also believe in discussion - may be I am missing something and your answer adds details which are missing in the dupe?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm just new to C. I didn't even know flushing buffers was a thing. Why is it a dupe?

Comment: I didn't ask the question, so you should direct that comment to person that did.  Many people answer duplicate questions because they don't bother checking or think the answer will be localised to the question or simply want to help with that particular issue.  That includes both you and SergeyA very recently, so lets stop with the hypocrisy, shall we.